# Failure of Fubini's theorem and the existence of the double integral

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

If the two iterated integrals of a function f(x,y) that we calculate under Fubini's theorem are different, then that means the integrals of the positive and negative parts of the function are both infinite, and thus the double integral does not exist.

Say we had some function where the integral of only one of the parts of the function was infinite - e.g. integral of the positive part of the function was infinite whereas the integral of the negative part was finite. In this instance, the condition for Fubini's theorem:

$$\iint_{R} |f(x,y)|d A < \infty $$

would be violated. So Fubini's theorem would fail. However, the double integral would still exist (positive infinity). My question is: is the failure of Fubini's theorem independent of a double integral existing?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking that you haven't already answered for yourself, or what you mean by "independent" here.  Yes, it's possible for the double integral to exist (and equal $\pm \infty$) even though the hypothesis $\iint |f|\,dA$ is not satisfied, in exactly the situation you describe.  In this case the two iterated integrals will equal $\pm \infty$ as well.  What else are you trying to find out?

Comment: @NateEldredge I just wanted some confirmation because I was thinking through the above scenario in my head and I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious or important. I'm not very well-versed in measure spaces and the other pure maths needed to understand the nuances of Fubini's theorem, so I wasn't too confident with the conclusion that I had come to. Thank you for the clarification though. I appreciate it. Would it be possible for you to suggest a function that behaves like I described?

Comment: @NateEldredge And would this be a good summary: (1) If the integrals of both positive and negative parts of the function are finite, then Fubini's theorem holds AND the double integral exists (2) If the integral of one of the parts of the function is finite and the other is infinite, Fubini's theorem does NOT hold but the double integral DOES exist (3) If the integrals of the positive and negative parts of the functions are both infinite, Fubini's theorem does NOT hold and the double integral does NOT exist? Are there any other cases I'm missing?

Comment: I think maybe I'm not sure exactly what statement you mean when you say "Fubini's theorem holds".  But for context, are you also aware of Tonelli's theorem, which says that for a nonnegative measurable function, the double integral always equals the iterated integral (though they may both equal $+\infty$)?  Basically everything there is to say here follows from applying Tonelli to the positive and negative parts.

Comment: I mean that you can use the iterated integrals to evaluate the double integral when I say "Fubini's theorem holds". I have heard about Tonelli's theorem and I did try to read into it but got slightly confused by the jargon about finite measure spaces and product measures and measurable functions :( That's why I have been trying to understand Fubini's theorem in simple terms - I'm trying to be as accurate as possible without delving into measure theory.